# Interior Points and Derivatives

Tags: analysis, derivatives

The question asks, Prove that if $y$ is an interior point of an interval $I$, then $f'(y)$ exists if and only if $f_+'$($y$)=$f_-$'($y$).

Going one way is pretty simple: $y$ is an interior point, so it is contained entirely in $I$. Assume $f_+'$($y$)=$f_-$'($y$), so $f'$ is continuous at $y$ and so $f$ is differentiable at $y$. I am having trouble going the other direction.

Thanks!

Comment: This has not much to do with derivatives I think. You are essentially asking for "the left and right limit exist *iff* the (general) limit exists" or "a function is left- and right-continuous in $x$ *iff* it is continuous in $x$". Maybe you can look this up.

Answer (score 0):

For $y$ be an interior point of $I$, then some $\delta>0$ is such that $(y-\delta,y+\delta)\subseteq I$, if $f'(y)$ exists, then for any $\epsilon>0$, there exists some $\delta'>0$ such that if $0<|h|<\delta'$, then $\left|\dfrac{f(y+h)-f(y)}{h}-f'(y)\right|<\epsilon$. Take $\eta=\min\{\delta,\delta'\}$, for all $0<h<\eta$, then $\left|\dfrac{f(y+h)-f(y)}{h}-f'(y)\right|<\epsilon$, this shows $f_{+}^{\prime}(y)=f'(y)$.